# how to uninstall conky?

Tags: debian, conky

Okay so I am facing an annoying issue where apt install just a different version of conky(all,standard,cli) every time I try to purge it. which is stupid. Below is a trimmed version where this happens. I checked other answers but apt remove purge worked for them.
but for me it installs itself like a virus or something. any Ideas? I am think if I could uninstall the package without any installation.

```
aditya@Aditya-lappy:~$ sudo apt remove --purge conky-all 
[sudo] password for aditya: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaudclient2 libxmmsclient6 libxnvctrl0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  conky-std
Suggested packages:
  apcupsd audacious moc mpd xmms2
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  conky-all*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  conky-std
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 340 kB of archives.
After this operation, 465 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 conky-std amd64 1.10.8-1+b1 [340 kB]
Fetched 340 kB in 10s (33.0 kB/s)
dpkg: conky-all: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 conky depends on conky-std | conky-cli | conky-all; however:
  Package conky-std is not installed.
  Package conky-cli is not installed.
  Package conky-all is to be removed.

(Reading database ... 249836 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing conky-all (1.10.8-1+b1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package conky-std.
(Reading database ... 249808 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../conky-std_1.10.8-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking conky-std (1.10.8-1+b1) ...
Setting up conky-std (1.10.8-1+b1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
(Reading database ... 249831 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for conky-all (1.10.8-1+b1) ...

aditya@Aditya-lappy:~$ sudo apt remove --purge conky-std
...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  conky-cli
...
aditya@Aditya-lappy:~$ sudo apt remove --purge conky-cli
...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  conky-std
Suggested packages:
  apcupsd audacious moc mpd xmms2
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  conky-cli*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  conky-std
...
Abort.
```

Comment: I tried --no-install-recommends did not work. still tries to install conky

Comment: you have another package installed which depends on `conky-std` or `conky-all` or `conky-cli`.  When you remove one of those, one of the others has to be installed to satisfy that dependency.  So to remove conky entirely, you also need to remove the package that depends on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `conky` package:

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove conky
```